# Omit all result if one row is equal to a certain value

Tags: php, sql, database, t-sql

I want to select a row (that appears multiple times) from a table ONLY if the column 'WRONG' never reads "YES".That means if the row exists 100 times and **only one time** WRONG=yes, then do no display ANY rows in the result.

*And if possible no variables and while loops please. If it can't be done, then go ahead and post a solution with a variable.

Here is an example of table structure:

table 1

```
USER--WRONG--otherColumns
bob              data   
bob              data 
bob              data 
bob              data     
bob              data
bob   YES        data
bob              data 
bob              data 
jon              data
```

RESULT should be:
jon  (because one time Wrong was equal to yes for the user bob)

This code ofcourse doesn't omit all bobs. Only one is omitted:

```
SELECT USER FROM table1 WHERE wrong <> 'yes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM table1 t2
   WHERE t1.user = t2.user
   AND wrong = 'yes');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select user
from table1 a
where not exists (select 1 from table1 b where a.user = b.user and wrong = 'yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    USER
FROM
    Mytable T1
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 3
       FROM Mytable T2
       WHERE T1.user = T2.User AND T2.Wrong = 'YES')
```

You can use EXCEPT too (tag says tsql) and this gives the same plan

```
SELECT
    USER
FROM
    Mytable
EXCEPT
SELECT
    USER
FROM
    Mytable
WHERE
    Wrong = 'YES'
```

And for the EXISTS haters. This assume the USER column has no NULLs, otherwise it fails

```
SELECT
    USER
FROM
    Mytable T1
WHERE
   T1.USER NOT IN (SELECT T2.USER
       FROM Mytable T2
       WHERE T2.Wrong = 'YES')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user from table1 where wrong <> 'yes' group by user
```

Comment: Wouldnt I still get 7 bobs? If Yes appears just once, all bobs must go!